# Redo log Oracle and commit

Tags: oracle, redo

in an linux OS, Oracle 12.2.0.1, in a transaction, i have a program first uses to increment 3 different values, an update returning (i can't use a sequencefor a lot of reason).
These values ​​are then used for inserts and updates of business data that are committed at the end of the transaction.
The program process 250,000 operations and I wanted to know if the 3 commits made at the time of the update returning could have a consequence on the redo logs?
The processing is parallelized on 20 parallels.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: why 3 commits ? can't you do it in a single transaction ? why even bother about redologs ?

Comment: Are there three commits per row, or three commits for all 250,000 rows?

Comment: there is 3 commit for each update returning to save the value so (3 * 250 000) + 250 000. It's a portage cobol program to oracle and i can't do what i want. The is a lot of redo log rotation

Comment: I should change the update returning by using a sequence but i can't

Comment: in fact I wonder the impact of intermediate commits on the frequency of redo and the fact that the processing is parallelized causing a lot of wait event log file sync